# Invoke Jscript profiler from outside Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, profiler

I've been unable to find the information but It may be quite simple.
Using IE8, you can profile your code (F12), is there a way to invoke this profiler on an object implementing the IWebBrowser2 interface ?

Basically, i've [CHtmlViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h6dke4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) hosting a [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. I'd like to use the new profiler on these objects, is this possible ? (i can't find a documentation more recent than .Net 3.0)

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces for profiling aren't on IWebBrowser2 but rather on the JavaScript engine and can be found in any host of the engine. Documentation for it is over at:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/cc836486(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/cc836486%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)
Alas it's not easy to get your own profiler going. If you can use IE11 or IE11 collecting an ETW trace would be your best bet for profiling IE outside of F12 or VS.